# How we can mock app.yml file to our test class

Tags: junit

app.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "local"
  banner:
    location: classpath:banner.txt
  servlet:
    context-path: /reps
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: "local"

reps:
  name: REPS
  redisPort: XXXX
  redisURL: 0.0.0.0
  kda-data-stream: a250377-wp4-umc-ert-kinesis-dev-use1
  database:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost
    user: XXXX
    pass: XXXXXXXX`
```

I am trying the below code but it's not covering it

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.URL),yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.USERNAME), yamlConfig.getDatabase().get(Constants.PASSWORD));
```